# php table <th> and <td> from Database Selected but they are not Matching in the right indexing position

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

all Developers.
I am developing School Management System, in the Database, I have two tables one is For Subjects, and the other one is designed for obtained marks of the Subjects and it is called scores.
So I am trying to fetch subject Names as Table Head

I have another Query below this query and I am trying to fetch from scores as table data .

At this point, I failed to match the subject name and its score from the scores table.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<head>
 <tr>
<?php
// Query for Subject Names

    $view_subject = $config->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjects");
    $view_subject->execute(); 
    while($row = $view_subject->fetch()){
        $sub_name = htmlspecialchars($row['sub_name']);
 ?>
 <th class="text-center"style="background-color:#395C7F;color:#fff;"><?php echo $sub_name;?></th>

<?php } ?>
 
</tr>
</thead>
<body>

<?php
// Query for Subject Scores
$view_scores = $config->prepare("SELECT * FROM scores INNER JOIN subjects ON scores.score_sub_id = subjects.sub_id WHERE scores.std_rand = :random_id ORDER BY scores.score_sub_id ASC");
$view_scores->execute(['random_id' => $rand_ID]); 
while($row = $view_scores->fetch()){

$score_id = htmlspecialchars($row['score_id']);
$score_sub_id = htmlspecialchars($row['score_sub_id']);
$score_mid_amount = htmlspecialchars($row['score_mid_amount']);
$score_final_amount = htmlspecialchars($row['score_final_amount']);

?>

<tr>
    <td class="text-black" data-title="Subject"><?php echo $score_mid_amount;?></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Database images:**
*1- Subjects table*
[image: Subjects table]

*2- Scores table*
[image]

** Browser UI **
[image]

Comment: On your second loop you have entered the '<tr>' inside the loop that is wrong and why this is happening to you. '<tr>' is a new line, you need to loop through all the '<td>'s before you change to the next line.

Comment: Also, if you have more than one line, you need another loop just for the lines - another loop that wraps the '<td>' loops for the '<tr>'...:)

Answer (score 1):

On your second loop you have entered '<tr>' wrapping each '<td>' that means that each one arrives at a different line , '<td>'s should be as much as there are '<th>' for each line.... so :

```
<?php
// Query for Subject Scores
$view_scores = $config->prepare("SELECT * FROM scores INNER JOIN subjects ON scores.score_sub_id = subjects.sub_id WHERE scores.std_rand = :random_id ORDER BY scores.score_sub_id ASC");
$view_scores->execute(['random_id' => $rand_ID]); 
?>
<tr> 
<?php
while($row = $view_scores->fetch()){

$score_id = htmlspecialchars($row['score_id']);
$score_sub_id = htmlspecialchars($row['score_sub_id']);
$score_mid_amount = htmlspecialchars($row['score_mid_amount']);
$score_final_amount = htmlspecialchars($row['score_final_amount']);

?>


    <td class="text-black" data-title="Subject"><?php echo $score_mid_amount;?></td>


<?php } ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This should fix your table but it will only create one line! if you have more than one line you will need to add another loop to wrap this one and it will create the new '<tr>' outside the inner loop.

BTW: I assume that the 2nd while loop is exactly long as the first one... since you are supposed to have the same amount of <td> per line per <th> if it's not in the same length or not sorted the same way you will have an issue... which can be resolved either by adjusting your SELECT or creating an array with ids and injecting to it the data from the second loop according to the keys brought in the first.